# Android Library: Obfuscate jar

Tags: android, gradle, jar, proguard, obfuscation

I have an android library project,  and I want to create a jar and obfuscate it. 
So far to create the jar I used this code:

```
//task to export contents as jar
task exportJar(dependsOn: exportOcs, type: Copy) {
  from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
  into('SDK/libs')
  include('classes.jar')
  rename('classes.jar', 'SDK' + getVersionString() + '.jar')
}
```

Is there a way to obfuscate that jar? or a way to create a jar that is already obfuscated? generally is whats the correct way to create an obfuscated library? 
(BTW yes I know I have to keep some of the classes not obfuscated) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Release buildType proguard will obfuscate the classs files that are used to create the jar. so no special handling is required:

```
 release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
```

and for the jar copying:

```
task exportJar(dependsOn: exportOcs, type: Copy) {
 from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
 into('SDK/libs')
 include('classes.jar')
 rename('classes.jar', 'SDK' + getVersionString() + '.jar')
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It either finishes with an error or hangs up and spins indefinitely.